# Java code indent wrong

Tags: android, emacs

When I am format a java code file in Emacs, if the code has function like this;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     //code block
}
```

I format it using C+M+\, it will be like

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //code block
}
```

I open the java file with mode `Java/l Android AC Abbre` in its fundamental bar. how to format it in correct way?

Comment: In eclipse go to code formating then edit the xml file you want or create a new one to your liking

Comment: "CTRL + I" should work fine.

Comment: sorry, CTRL + I doesn't work either. By the way, I am using emacs for coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more recent version of emacs (maybe just upgrading java-mode is enough for you).  24.3.1 workd fine for me, but I don't recall when this was fixed.

This is a workaround for the indentation issue ([here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingJava) is the source):

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        "Treat Java 1.5 @-style annotations as comments."
        (setq c-comment-start-regexp "(@|/(/|[*][*]?))")
        (modify-syntax-entry ?@ "< b" java-mode-syntax-table)))
```

Comment: thanks, this solution can solve my problem. I think others who are using old version Emacs may have the same problem.